# Convert int to 0-1 float

Tags: c#, math

I wonder why my next statement always returns 1, and how I can fix it. I accounted for integer division by casting the first element in the division to float. Apart from that I'm not getting much further.

```
int value = any int;
float test = (float)value / int.MaxValue / 2 + 1;
```

By the way my intention is to make this convert ANY integer to a 0-1 float

Comment: That won't compile - what did you initialise `value` to?

Comment: Not always return 0. int value = int.MaxValue --> test == 1.5  ,  int value = -int.MaxValue --> test == 0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't always return zero. For example, this code:

```
int value = 12345678;
float test = (float)value / int.MaxValue / 2 + 1;
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Prints 1.002874

The problem is that floats are not very precise, so for small values of `value`, the result will be 0 to the number of digits of precision that floats can handle.

For example, `value == 2300` will print `0`, but `value == 2400` will print `1.000001`.

If you use `double` you get better results:

```
int value = 1;
double test = (double)value / int.MaxValue / 2 + 1;
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Prints `1.00000000023283`

Comment: In fact it almost never returns 1. It only prints 1 for small values

Comment: Alright now that's some useful information. If someone told me it was about the precision I would've got it right away =)

Comment: I guess I'll just change the input type to something less big.

Answer (score 4):

To rescale a number in the range `s..e` to `0..1`, you do `(value-s)/(e-s)`.
So in this case:

```
double d = ((double)value - int.MinValue) / ((double)int.MaxValue - int.MinValue);
float test = (float)d;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Avoid implicit type conversions**. Use all elements in your expression of type double, if that is the type you want. Convert the `int.MaxValue` and the `2` to `double` before using them in the division, so that no implicit type conversions are involved.

Also, you might want to **parenthesize** your expression to make it more readable. As it is, it is error prone.

Finally, if your expression is too complex and you don't know what's going on, **split it** into simpler expressions, all of them of type `double`.

P.S.: By the way, trying to get precise results and using `float` instead of `double` is not a very wise thing to do. **Use `float` for precise floating point calculations.**

Comment: double test1 = (double)inputint / (double)int.MaxValue;
double test2 = test1 / 2d;
float result = (float)(test2 / 1d);

this still yields 1 every time.

Comment: @Villermen Then look at every single step and find out the _exact_, isolated place where the result of the calculation is different from your expectations.

Comment: I did that. It gives fractional results up till the point I add up the 1. Then the whole answer suddenly becomes 1

Comment: @Villermen Then use double instead of float. Clearly if your fractional result is 0.15 you won't get 1 after adding 1 - you will get 1.15. If your fractional results are close to 0 then you are running into a precision problem. No float should appear in your code if you want to be precise. They should be double.